# Cafe Mai vietnamese coffee - what is the US equivalent?

Tags: bean-varieties

I was at an AirBnb in Washington DC and the host (or previous guest) had left coffee in the cupboard. Only enough for 12 cups or so, and I'm feeling guilty that I consumed the entire packet over couple of days without replenishing.  Anyway, it was 'Cafe Mai' brand like so:

[image]

And I am wondering what is the nearest thing I can buy in the US. Flying to Vietnam to visit the (famous) coffee shop isn't going to happen any time soon :(

I can see a few types on their website (http://cafemai.vn), like "Paris Mai", "Moca", "Aliculi Dac Lac", "Espresso Viet Nam", "Buon Me Thuot", but I can't work out from the photos what I had.

Answer (score 4):

I would say that the easiest way to get authentic vietnamese coffee in Washington DC would be to go to an asian supermarket and buy a pack of vietnamese coffee. I've never been to DC, but I just googled "Asian supermarket in Washington DC" and also "Vietnamese supermarket in Washington DC" and plenty of option show up. So it should be easy to pick one that's close to you.

Other than that vietnamese coffee is of the Robusta species and the roast profile is quite dark. So you can also just go to a well sorted supermarket and buy a pack of Robusta dark roast beans/grounds, preferably of vietnamese origin. It will be more or less the same as the coffee roasted by vietnamese roasters.